# Yii2 save() creating DB row with default values

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to implement a login method using OpenID, and the $_SESSION var's are posting correctly - and through those I am simply trying to register users in MySQL. For some reason, when passing through the 'login' action in my controller ::

```
    public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    include ('../views/user-record/steamauth/userInfo.php');

    $steamid = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];
    $username = $_SESSION['steam_personaname'];
    $profileurl = $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'];
    $avatar = $_SESSION['steam_avatar'];
    $avatarmedium = $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'];
    $avatarfull = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];

    $user = UserRecord::findBySteamId($steamid);

    if ($user === null)
    {
        $user = new UserRecord();

        $user->steamid = $steamid;
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->profileurl = $profileurl;
        $user->avatar = $avatar;
        $user->avatarmedium = $avatarmedium;
        $user->avatarfull = $avatarfull;
        $user->verified = 0;
        $user->banned = 0;

        $user->save();
    }

    Yii::$app->user->login($user, 604800);

    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->returnUrl);
}
```

EDIT: Here is the UserRecord class, forgot to add it in.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class UserRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $steamid;
    public $username;
    public $profileurl;
    public $avatar;
    public $avatarmedium;
    public $avatarfull;

    public $verified;
    public $banned;
    public $rank;
    public $authKey;

//    public $password;
//    public $accessToken;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function getAuthKey() 
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return self::findOne($id);
    }

    public function validateSteamID($steamid)
    {
        return $this->steamid === $steamid;
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new \yii\base\NotSupportedException;
    }

    public static function findBySteamId($steamid)
    {
        return self::findOne(['steamid' => $steamid]);
    }

}
```

The result is simply a posted row, with none of the data entered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: the filed you are using in define in your modal attribute array???

Comment: Updated it @Dani thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have redefine the same columns name using public vars  these override the vars for activeRecord and then are saved  only empty value ..

if this you must remove the (redifined) public vars in your model

otherwise  if you have no rules  then

Try adding safe  at the attribute in you model rules

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      [['steamid', 'username', 'profileurl', 'avatar', 'avatarmedium', 
               'avatarfull', 'verified', 'banned', 'rank', 'authKey',], 'safe'],
   ];
 }
```

Comment: I did this and it is still posting SQL default values, very odd to me.

Comment: I have update the answer  with an important suggestion  .. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Declaring 'public' variables made the save() ignore the data being posted. Thanks.